# Scale Component Flex for card-designer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I want To Make Some Ruler (Scale) like Component Which Will Show Inch,Mm,Cm -> etc And Will Change It On Mouse Move... Actually I Want It For Card-Designer / T-Shirt Designer... I Know I Have To Make It From Scratch But If I Use H-Slider Or Just Make It With UI Component ??? Is Someone Have Any Idea About It

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can HaveIdea From -> https://github.com/org-beeant/InchRuler it is not that you are searching but you will get IDEA for your ruler ... Good Luck